# Command line speed test

Tags: bandwidth, performance

There are several sites that give you decent speedtest metrics (DSLReports, Speakeasy; PhonePower even has additional VoIP-related metrics). I want to get these metrics on a periodic basis. Ideally, I want to put something as a shell script and cron it on the router. So, here are the questions:

1. Does anybody know a website that provides this information to command-based clients?
2. Websites usually download several files of different sizes. What size are most representative? Do they average the results? I tried downloading (through wget) a distro from kernel.org and a 500MB file from softlayer.com - and got several times difference comparing with GUI. 700KB/s (~6Mbps) compared to 16Mbps in DSLR and PhonePower.
3. Is there any reliable high-speed server where I can try upload speed? How about (men can dream!) VoIP metrics, like jitter or latency?

Everybody on Google discusses "how can I measure download from command line" with the answer "use wget/curl". Can we go one step beyond that?

Comment: All the speed test sites I've used are specifically designed to deter command line usage, so you may not find what you're after. Allowing command line usage would open the system to massive abuse.

Answer (score 3):

As you are obviously fine with estimates, use [`bing`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/bing). There are also a couple of public [`iperf`](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/) servers available - just run a Google query or use iperf.eltel.net if you feel lazy today. Iperf in UDP mode is also capable of providing packet loss rate and jitter informaion.

If you need consistent and reliable information, you obviously should not rely on free public services, but run your own, monitored iperf servers.

Comment: Some public servers listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf#Public_test_servers